# Issues with eigen.analysis in popbio

Tags: r

I've been trying to calculate demographic rates using the 'popbio' package in R.  I was trying to get the sensitivity of the eigenvalues but keep getting the error "Error in Mod(z$values) : non-numeric argument to function".  So, I tried to run the example from the 'popbio' package and got the same error.  From the example in the package manual:

```
A<-matrix(c(0,0,2,.3,0,0,0,.6,0), nrow=3,byrow=TRUE) #matrix from example
ev <- eigen.analysis(A) # calculation of eigenvalues
Error in Mod(z$values) : non-numeric argument to function #error I get for example and my data
```

I know that the function needs a matrix.  Since object "A" is a matrix, I'm confused on why I'm getting the error.  Any help on why I'm getting this error would be greatly appreciated!  I'm pretty new to using R for this stuff, so apologies if this is the wrong place for this question.

Cheers,
Kevin

Answer (score 0):

If you run into problems with a function in an add-on package,  I would run through each line of code and then ask a more general question.  For example,

1. Type `eigen.analysis` and hit return to see the code below (and line 4 is the only call to Modulus used for damping ratio)

   ```
   ev <- eigen(A)
   lmax <- which.max(Re(ev$values))
   lambda <- Re(ev$values[lmax])
   dr <- rle(round(Mod(ev$values), 5))$values
   ...
   ```
2. If you get an error running

   ```
   A <- matrix(c(0,0,2,.3,0,0,0,.6,0), nrow=3,byrow=TRUE)
   ev <- eigen(A)
   Mod(ev$values)
   ```

then ask that question on Stack Overflow instead.

3. Just a guess, but I'm not sure why you see Error in Mod(z$values) instead of Mod(ev$values) unless you have some updated eigen.analysis script.

Comment: thanks for the tip.  It looks like it was a bug with the version of R I was running (or rather a bug in the package in the version of R, I guess).  Since going back to version 3.1.2, I've not gotten an error.